# How to mention ingest pipeline name while indexing data through hibernate search

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am using elastic search with hibernate,have created one ingest pipeline processor in elastic search.But I am not able to find out where I have to mention pipeline name.Is there any hibernate property or any annotation to mention pipeline name?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any hibernate property or any annotation to mention pipeline name?

In the current versions (the latest so far being 5.8.0.CR1), there isn't such a property or annotation, and you have no way of manipulating the HTTP request parameters. So I'm afraid you cannot use pipelines with Hibernate Search.

If you think this feature should be added, you can create a ticket [on our JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH), explaining your use case in details: the more information we have, the more likely we are to find a good solution for your use case.